# Prevent an <input /> out of sight, from scrolling the page into view when selected() (or onFocus)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a JS code that selects an input's content with jQuery's `$element.select()` on mouse over of the input's parent.

I want to prevent the browser scrolling the input into view when it gets selected (and also gets focus I think?) it's out of sight, because the page is an array of thumbnails with the input below each one and what this does is a chain reaction that scrolls all the way to the bottom of the page, if you don't move the mouse away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$('#childInput').on('focus',function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
 });


$('#parentDiv').on('mouseover',function()
{
   var temp= $('body').scrollTop();
   var temp1=$('body').scrollLeft();
   $('#childInput').select();
   $('body').scrollTop(temp);
   $('body').scrollLeft(temp1);
});
```

Comment: If this solves your problem then please acknowledge my effort by accepting the answer. This keeps me motivated. If any doubt feel free to ask.